# youtube repeat oneliner

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am trying to make a oneliner to repeat videos.

I started looking for that replay button to trigger another round:

```
$("[title='Replay']")[0].click();
```

A self calling function to loop in the background while the vid is running.

```
rpt=function(){setTimeout(function(){alert("blarg");rpt()},5000)}
```

putting those two things together and adding a tiny bit of fluff:
`$ = jQuery` to initialize shiny $()-syntax and finally `rpt();`to get things rolling:

```
$=jQuery,rpt=function(){setTimeout(function(){$("[title='Replay']")[0].click(),rpt()},100)};rpt();
```

alas, the parts work but not the whole thing

I noticed that the console is printing an error message if I enter the final line before the video has finished; since the button is not found yet and therefore a call to `.click()` on undefined isn't working.

Shouldn't the function still loop in the background and trigger during a later call, as soon as the replay button is there for jQuery to grab?

I'm using chrome 44.0.2403.130 and jQuery: 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a verification to make sure there is a replay element available.

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

By default (and unless you use other conflicting libraries), jQuery is assigned to the `$` variable on its initialization.

`setInterval(function(){if($("[title='Replay']").length)$("[title='Replay']").trigger('click');},100);`

Comment: the assignment of `$` seems to be only necessary while using the browser extension and that's why i used it here but i don't plan to investigate it. anyway, thanks for answer because it now works and i guess i better go read the documentation for setInterval now ^^

Answer (score 1):

one line repeat + number of repeat appended in title:

```js
var title=$('#eow-title').innerHTML; var replaysN = 1; setInterval(function(){if($('.ytp-play-button').title == 'Replay') {$('.ytp-play-button').click();$('#eow-title').innerHTML = title+' (x'+replaysN+')';replaysN++;} }, 1000);
```

..after some weeks after making this post, there was a new feature in youtube :D
After right-click on video -> Loop 
So every customization is useless :)